# Stop Bxslider on Click when In Ticker Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am using bxslider in ticker mode to display a row of images that I have added a light box to. Everything works fine but when I click I want to stop the show.

It seems this is easy to do in non-ticker mode but ticker mode runs the [`tickerLoop()`](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/blob/master/jquery.bxslider.js#L889) function which won't stop.

There is a function that stops the show on hover and I thought I could modify that but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
var slider = $('.portfolio-slider').bxSlider({
                          minSlides: 4,
                          maxSlides: 4,
                          slideWidth: 170,
                          slideMargin: 10,
                          ticker: true,
                          speed: 30000,
                          tickerHover:true,
                          useCSS:false
                         });
    $('.portfolio-slider').click(function (l){
             $('a[rel*=facebox-cap]').facebox();
                      slider.stopShow,
                      slider.startShow
             }

            });
```

EDIT:

It almost works using this:

```
                var slider_config = {
                      minSlides: 4,
                          maxSlides: 4,
                          slideWidth: 170,
                          slideMargin: 10,
                          ticker: true,
                          speed: 30000,
                          tickerHover:true,
                          useCSS:false
                    }
var slider = $('.portfolio-slider').bxSlider(slider_config);


 $('ul.portfolio-slider  li').on({
  click: function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
                $('a[rel*=facebox-cap]').facebox();

    var slide_index = slider.getCurrentSlide();
    slider_config['speed'] = 0;
    slider_config['startSlide'] = slide_index;  
    slider.reloadSlider(slider_config);
  },
  mouseleave: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    var slide_index = slider.getCurrentSlide();
   slider_config['speed'] = 30000;
    slider_config['startSlide'] = slide_index;  
    slider.reloadSlider(slider_config);
  }
});
```

That code at least lets me modify the settings the reload the slider. The only problem is that it looks really tacky and doesn't work right with the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

never used this but take a look at this example http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls
it seems you can use [stopAuto()](http://bxslider.com/options) on your click event.

Comment: aah i see, can't you set speed to 0 on click and when you close the modal set it back

Comment: I was trying to do that. Just not sure how to call the `tickerLoop()` function from my external JavaScript. I get a `function undefined` error. It looks like the function is setup as `tickerLoop(Speed)` so it should be easy to set the speed.

Comment: did you tried setting slider.settings.speed? worst case i would say enter an issue ticket for this plugin or very hack y but destroy and reload the slider on click if destroying doesn't mess up the css

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have played with destroy/reload the problem is then it starts over at the beginning instead of continuing. Let me try `slider.settings.speed`

Comment: slider.settings.speed is undefined :(

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is following the link, you should prevent this to happen maybe it will work as you want, and I did not understand clear you want

```
 $('.portfolio-slider').click(function (event){
             event.preventDefault()

             $('a[rel*=facebox-cap]').facebox();
                      slider.stopShow,
                      slider.startShow
             }
```

edit : you can see the rash tag on url when you click, it should not happen

Comment: :( that didn't work. I think the problem is that the `tickerloop()` overrides the `slider.Stop/Start` functions.